# How does EncodeFloat work in Google Protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

So thay have:

```
inline uint32 WireFormatLite::EncodeFloat(float value) {
  union {float f; uint32 i;};
  f = value;
  return i;
}
```

And I do not get it. we have not sen any  value into `i`... so how? What happens here?

Answer (score 1):

In a union, the members' storage overlaps. If the two members have the same size (ie if you can `assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32))`) *and* alignment, then what you're really doing is:

1. store a `float` to the location of `f`
2. read a `uint32` from the location of `i`, *which is the same location*

You could equally

```
return *reinterpret_cast<uint32 *>(&value);
```

(again, so long as you're certain both types are the same size, and have the same alignment requirements).

Comment: This is sometimes called "type punning," and according to the 03 Standard if evokes Undefined Behavior.  However many compilers specifically allow it.